# How to correctly build recursion with 3 variables?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to crack down how recursions work.I've seen the working of simple ones, but now I am solving the excercise, where I need to take in consideration 3 variables.
It sounds like:

### Task

> Generate all strings with the given number of zeroes, ones and twos and output them in 
>   lexicographical order.
>
> input formate: 3 non-negative values which are a + b + C <= 12,
>
> output formate: all string with `a` zeros, `b` ones and `c` twos
>
> Example 1.

```
input: 1 1 1

output:
012
021
102
120
201
210
```

> Example 2

```
input: 0 0 0
output:
```

I would REALLY appreciate if you can give me some advices how to do it and,more importantly, some **resources that helped you** to reach the 'enlightment'(or at least better understanding) how to build recursions.Now I can only think of manually creating the tree on the paper when modifying the initial non-recursive algorithm.It's not the first time I get stuck at recursion,so I am determined to finally work it out.

I would also appreciate the solution,but please,mark it with some bold text so I won't be tempted to look directly at the it.

If it saves you some time, here is my broken prototype to generate in incorrect order
Value renews itself for some reason(debugging didn't give an answer).And I can only think of building some cheker in loop to see which number to add to the given array(according to a,b,c).

### Prototype

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    if c > 0:
        prev = foo(a, b, c - 1)
    if b > 0:
        prev = foo(a, b - 1, c)
    if a == 0:
        return ['']
    prev = foo(a - 1, b, c)
    result = []
    for p in prev:
        result.append(p + '0')
        result.append(p + '1')
        result.append(p + '2')
    return result
print(foo(1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem, for there are many more permutations than your example 1. shows

Comment: @user508402, sorry, but I don't really understand the question.I added some formate information given at the excercise,but could you please clarify what do you mean?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "generate all permutations recursion", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Also work through a tutorial on recursion, paying attention to "base case" and "recursion case".

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do two things:

1. Identify the base case. That's when the recursion should end.

> In this case, it's when all inputs are 0

2. Figure out how you can reduce other inputs to the base case.

> Here you first find all strings (in lexicographical order, using recursion) that start with a 0, and add a zero to the start of them. You will have to reduce the count of zeros by one in recursive call. After that, do the same for 1 and 2, collect all the results and return them.

Here's the code:

```
pastebin.com/GNNCN1Uf
```